# Loops in django 1.8 views

Tags: python, django

I have a `models.py` where I specify a class with 3 `ImageFields` and 3 `CharFields`. The CharFields contain youtube video id's which I want to use in `detail.html`. But I don't know how I am supposed to refer to the elements in `details.html`

My `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Feat(models.Model):
    feat_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="feature1")
    feat_img1 = models.ImageField(upload_to="%Y/%m/%d",default="1992/08/92")
    feat_img2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="%Y/%m/%d",default="1992/08/92")
    feat_img3 = models.ImageField(upload_to="%Y/%m/%d",default="1992/08/92")
    feat_vid1 = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="3NQRhE772b0")
    feat_vid2 = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="XU3h3CVI_gI")
    feat_vid3 = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="vqHIQD4_lu4")
    num = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):              
  return self.feat_name
```

`view.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from .models import Feat


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'feature/base.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_feat_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Feat.objects.order_by('-num')[:1]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Feat
    template_name = 'feature/detail.html'
```

`base.html`

```
{% if latest_feat_list %}
<ul>
{% for feat in latest_feat_list %}
<a href="{% url 'feature:detail' feat.id %}"><img src="{{    feat.feat_img1.url }}" alt="ac/dc">
<a href="{% url 'feature:detail' feat.id %}"><img src="{{ feat.feat_img2.url }}" alt="ac/dc">
<a href="{% url 'feature:detail' feat.id %}"><img src="{{  feat.feat_img3.url  }}" alt="ac/dc">
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No </p>
{% endif %}
```

`detail.html`

```
{% for `condition` %}
<img id="hide" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/{{ choice.feat_vid1  }}/hqdefault.jpg" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ choice.feat_vid1  }}?autoplay=1" width="480" height="300"/>
<img id="hide" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/{{ choice.feat_vid2  }}/hqdefault.jpg" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ choice.feat_vid2  }}?autoplay=1" width="480" height="300"/>
<img id="hide" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/{{ choice.feat_vid3  }}/hqdefault.jpg" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ choice.feat_vid3  }}?autoplay=1" width="480" height="300"/>


{% endfor %}
```

my applications `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='base'),
 url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),

]
```

I need to display all the ids passed in `Feat`class in `detail.html` but don't know how to refer to the elements in `Feat`.

Comment: A `DetailView` will make the selected object of the `Feat` model available in the `feat` context variable. See [`get_context_object_name()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_object_name). The charfields are then `feat.feat_vid1`, `feat.feat_vid2`, ...

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more.I am a beginner and I can't understand how this function can be used in detailview to display the selected videos

Comment: Can you add the part of your `urls.py` where you reference the `DetailView`? I should be able to build you an explanation by example from there.

Comment: I have edited that part. I want that once you click on any of the feature images, it should take you to a video of that id. Say for feat_img1 it should take you to feat_vid1. Thanks in advance for taking the time.

Comment: For what do you need 3 * 2 same fields in the same Model, is there any purpose or you just don't know to to organize it correctly?

Comment: @pythad The function is to display three images and when the user clicks over any of them a video related to that image is displayed. I'm sure it can be done more efficiently but I've just started out and this seemed alright.Help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to implement

`The function is to display three images and when the user clicks over any of them a video related to that image is displayed. I'm sure it can be done more efficiently but I've just started out and this seemed alright.Help me out?`

It's a little bit different from what you've done, but still...
I won't describe the code as it will take really long time, but I will be glad to answer any of your questions. Also I highly recommend you to read docs on django's models.

**models.py** :

```
from django.db import models


class Feat(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='path/')
    youtube_link = models.URLField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Feat"
        verbose_name_plural = "Feats"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py** :

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from .models import Feat


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'feature/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_feats'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Feat.objects.order_by('-created')

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Feat
    template_name = 'feature/detail.html' 
    context_object_name = 'feat'
```

**index.html** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if latest_feats %}
    <ul>
        {% for feat in latest_feats %}
        <a href="{% url 'feature:detail' feat.id %}"><img src="{{ feat.image.url }}" alt="some text"></a>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
    <p>No </p>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

**detail.html** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe width="560" height="345" src="{{ feat.youtube_link }}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**urls.py** :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

There are many unbeautiful things. For example it would be much more better to implement template inheritance, but I think these will be enough for right now.

Comment: When implementing this code,while the `index.html` works, the reference to `detail.html` gives an error `Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(4,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']`. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: @turtle, first of all I would recomend you to check if you have pattern like `'r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$'`, because your `'r$(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$'` has 2 `$` in a single line and this is quite strange, as `$` means end of a line so I believe you can't have 2 in 1 line. Another common mistake is to use namespaces in your project urls but to forget to use them in your urls `namespace:name`.